# How do I toggle visibility on a specific material group?

Tags: materials, visibility

I have a mesh with diffuse and normal textures, and I've parted it out into several groups so I could distinguish metallic sections from non-metallic.  Let's say that the main texture group is A, the metallic portions are B, and then I've got a sub-section of B, which I'll call C.  C has the same material settings as B, but I distinguished it from B in the hopes I could toggle its visibility.

Just for context, C is a mask that covers part of the character's face, and I'd like the option of showing the character with and without the mask.  How can I do this in Blender?

Comment: This part which you call C which you say is a mask, is it an image texture (ie. the mask is an image) or is some faces selected to assign to a new material slot?

Comment: It's a literal mask that the character is wearing, so yes, it's some faces of the mesh selected and assigned to a new material slot.  B and C both have the exact same material setup.  I separated C into a new material group in the hopes that I could toggle it on and off.

Comment: So you just need to hide the mask's geometry and this geometry is part of the mesh you are working with and you don't want to seperate it right?

Comment: I'd prefer not to separate the geometry.  This model has an armature and animation attached, and I'm worried that attempting to split up the model will mess all that up.

Comment: In that case the answer that I have provided will work perefectly fine.

Comment: Some supporting screenshots may have been helpful to figure out what you are doing and might have spared some comments asking for clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Mask modifier.

Select the faces that you want to hide and put them into a Vertex Group. Now just use that group in the Mask modifier and click the invert option next to it. You can now toggle on and off the visibility of this modifier to see your character with and without the mask.

You can also add a custom property to use it to drive your modifier's visibility.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!